# Python3 AttributeError when setting properties using **kwargs

Tags: python, attributeerror

Simply put I do understand why I can't set a property using a `for` loop with `**kwargs` like so:

```
class Person():
    def __init__(self, onevar, *args, **kwargs):
        self.onevar = onevar
        for k in kwargs:
            self.k = kwargs[k]
            print(k, self.k)   

def run():
    ryan = Person('test', 4, 5, 6, name='ryan', age='fifty')
    print(ryan.name)

def main():
    run()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

This returns the following:

```
AttributeError: 'Person' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Anyone know why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you assign `self.k` you're not actually creating an attribute named the *value* of `k`, you're just creating an attribute called `k` repeatedly. If I understand what you're trying to do, you need to replace

```
self.k = kwargs[k]
```

with

```
setattr(self, k, kwargs[k])
```

to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: @tzaman's answer is better. Use `setattr` as he suggests.

You're expecting `k` to become the variable but it doesn't work that way. However you can extend the base `object` in Python and set your variables using the internal `__dict__` property.

You can also use `iteritems()` to get the value directly.

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, onevar, *args, **kwargs):
        self.onevar = onevar
        for k,v in kwargs.iteritems():
            self.__dict__[k] = v
            print(k, self.__dict__.get(k))
```

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation here. With your way is `__dict__` specific only to instances of `Person`?

Comment: no, `__dict__` is part of the `object` base class. It's really not the best way to do it though.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
            self.k = kwargs[k]
```

... is setting `self.k` - the attribute of `self` named `k` - each time through the loop, **not**  `self.value_of_k` as you imagine.

If you change the line to

```
            setattr(self, k, kwargs[k])
```

you should get the result you want.